# Solving $y'' + 2y' + 2y = 0$: How to eliminate imaginary unit from solution?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

> $$y'' + 2y' + 2y = 0$$

$\downarrow$ *(write characteristic equation)*

$\lambda^2 +2\lambda + 2 = 0$

$\downarrow$ *(solve characteristic equation)*

$\lambda = -1 \pm i$

$\downarrow$ *(write general solution)*

$y = Ae^{(-1 - i)t} + Be^{(-1 + i)t}$

$\downarrow$ *(apply Euler's formula)*

$y = Ae^{-t}(\cos(-t) + i\sin(-t)) + Be^{-t}(\cos(t) + i\sin(t))$

$\downarrow$ *(perform minor algebra/trig rearrangement)*

$y = (A + B)e^{-t}\cos(t) + (B - A)e^{-t}\sin(t)i$

> Where do I go from here to eliminate the $i$?  Plugging in the exponential formulas for sine and cosine leads back to the original general solution, with $i$'s remaining.

Comment: Remember that $A$ and $B$ can in principle be complex numbers

Comment: @user10478: In other words, $i$ is just a number that can absorbed into the constant and those constants can be absorbed as a single constant.

Comment: O_O Is this the case for all differential equations; the constants in the general solution "secretly" represent arbitrary complex numbers, not just real?  What about quaternions, octonions, etc?

Comment: @user10478 You can choose any constant for which the differential equation makes sense. Typically we consider differential equations over $\mathbb{C}$ but I suppose one could use quarternions etc.

Comment: I applaud you on the way you’ve written out your explanation for each step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both $(A+B)$ and $(B-A)i$ are arbitrary constants. Rename them $C_1$ and $C_2$ to get the general solution
$$y=C_1e^{-t}\cos{(t)}+C_2e^{-t}\sin{(t)}$$

Answer (score 1):

In real solutions the coefficients of complex conjugate terms are themselves complex conjugates.  So if you render

$y=\color{blue}{(A+Bi)}e^{(-1+i)t}+\color{blue}{(A-Bi)}e^{(-1-i)t}$

and carry through as in the question, the factors of $i$ will cancel naturally.