# Real solution of this ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the solution of this o.d.e $$y''''+3y''+2y=0$$ is

$y=c_1 \cos(\sqrt{2}x)+i c_1 \sin(\sqrt{2}x)+c_2\cos(\sqrt{2}x)-ic_2\sin(\sqrt{2}x)+c_3\cos(x)+ic_3\sin(x)+c_4\cos(x)-ic_4\sin(x)$

I want to find the solution in R, so i put the imaginer part 0 that is

$c_1 \sin(\sqrt{2}x)-c_2 \sin(\sqrt{2}x)+c_3\sin(x)-c_4\sin(x)=0$

this give me that $c_1=c_2$ and $c_3=c_4$

conclusion I get that $$ y(x)= 2c_1 \cos(\sqrt{2}x)+2c_3 \cos(x)$$ but this is not the right solution where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic equation is $\lambda^4+3\lambda^2+2=0.$ We substitute $\alpha=\lambda^2$ to obtain $\alpha^2+3\alpha+2=0,$ with solutions $\alpha=-1, -2.$ It follows that the general solution is given by
$$y(x)=A\sin\left(\sqrt{2}x\right)+B\cos\left(\sqrt{2}x\right)+C\sin(x)+D\cos(x). $$
You don't need the complex numbers anywhere, because essentially the complex numbers mean oscillatory behavior, which is captured already by using the trig functions.

Comment: but from where we get this I don't know it !!!

Comment: please I don't know this @Adrian Keister  how we get it from the complex version

Comment: are you here @Adrian Keister

Comment: This is simply the standard form of the ansatz. It's the time-honored guess-and-check method of solving DE's.

Comment: @Vrouvrou See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321493/solving-y-2y-2y-0-how-to-eliminate-imaginary-unit-from-solution/3321495#3321495) question

Answer (score 0):

Using your expression, group terms to get$$y=\left(c_1-c_2\right) i \sin \left(\sqrt{2} x\right)+\left(c_3-c_4\right) i \sin
   (x)+\left(c_1+c_2\right) \cos \left(\sqrt{2} x\right)+\left(c_3+c_4\right) \cos
   (x)$$
A constant being a constant, this becomes
$$y=d_1 \sin \left(\sqrt{2} x\right)+d_2 \sin
   (x)+d_3 \cos \left(\sqrt{2} x\right)+d_4 \cos
   (x)$$